# BST total depth complication

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, depth

Here is an excerpt of a working BST:

```
class BinaryTree():

    def __init__(self,rootid):
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.rootid = rootid
    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.left
    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.right
    def setNodeValue(self,value):
        self.rootid = value
    def getNodeValue(self):
        return self.rootid
```

I decided not to display every function of the class above, only the important ones for what I am trying to achieve.

What I would like is to calculate the total depth of every node in the tree, and I attempted to use the following function:

```
def depth(tree, count=1):
    if tree != None:
        return count + depth(tree.getLeftChild(), count+1) + depth(tree.getRightChild(), count+1)
```

The `count=1` represents the idea that the root node has a depth of 1.

The problem with this function, however, is that it crashes when it reaches a `None` node, and I do not know how to fix it.

This is the error message I get when I try utilizing the function:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function `depth` needs a break condition:

```
def depth(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(depth(tree.getLeftChild()), depth(tree.getRightChild()))
```

And you forgot a `max` around the depths of the subtrees.

Your snippet above fails as soon as `tree == None` (when a node has no child on whatever side). Then nothing is returned, which implicitly returns `None` in Python.

Comment: this is great, Ill accept it in a minute. But can you explain what the use of the `max` is? Wouldn't this work in the absence of it as well?

Comment: It's how the BST depth is defined. Adding both depths of the subtrees would return the overall node count.

Comment: Oh, I accidently copy-pasted your `+`.

Comment: yeah, I figured. Thanks for the help